# Can't connect to Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, remote-desktop, rdp, remote-access

I have a dedicated server with Windows Server 2012 installed on it. I'm connecting with it through RDP.

Today I've enabled firewall and right away I was disconnected. Now I can't connect at all. I receive "Remote Desktop can’t connect to the remote computer" error message. With other server I can connect trough RDP, so the fault isn't on my side.

What can I do in current situation?

Comment: Can you do any remote management to disable the firewall? Or can you get to the console of the server?

Comment: I don't know. Can you explain, how to get to the console or remote management?

Comment: I'm not sure how to respond to a question about how to get to the console. You know like when you are not using remote desktop and you are standing right in front of the server? Or when you are working on the hypervisor? Is this the first time you've worked on a server?

Comment: Here's some information on remote management, it's a big topic: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh921475(v=ws.11).aspx 
 Here's a link to download the Remote Server Administration Tools: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520 All of this requires credentials that have admin rights on the server(s) to be managed.

Answer (score 2):

Your option is to go to the server and log into it directly and enable the firewall exception for RDP.

If this is a virtual machine (in HyperV/VMWare/etc), you should be able to use their management tools to get to the console and log in.  If this is a physical device, you'll need to go to where it is and allow the exception.